# ¿Como obtener los valores de un formulario de selects?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, formularios, html-select

Tengo este tipo de preguntas en el formulario:

```
<form>
        <label for="Pregunta1">Beber agua</label>
            <select id = "Pregunta1" name="Pregunta1" onchange="obtenerValor(this.id)">
                <option value="0">Nunca</option> 
                <option value="1">Casi nunca</option> 
                <option value="2">A veces</option>
                <option value="3">Bastantes veces</option>
                <option value="4">Casi siempre</option>
            </select>

        <label for="Pregunta2">Ir al baño</label>
            <select id = "Pregunta2" name="Pregunta2" onchange="obtenerValor(this.id)">
                <option value="0">Nunca</option> 
                <option value="1">Casi nunca</option> 
                <option value="2">A veces</option>
                <option value="3">Bastantes veces</option>
                <option value="4">Casi siempre</option>
            </select>
        <input type ="button" value ="Enviar" onclick="enviar()">

    </form>
```

Y tengo esta función que me recoge los valores y me funciona bien. Lo que pasa es que si por ejemplo se cambia de opcion, los 2 valores se guardan es decir, el 1 que se eligió y el 2 por el que se cambia.

```
 var valor = 0;
  
        function obtenerValor(id){
                valor += parseInt(document.getElementById(id).value);
                return valor; 
            }
        function enviar(){
            console.log("valor enviado", valor);
        }
```

He intentado llamar a la funcion de obtenerValor(id) en la de enviar() pero no funciona. Lo que necesito es que se recojan los valores pero una vez enviados, no que si se cambia de opcion el valor anterior permanece guardado (ese no deberia guardarse).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes reducir todo eso a esto:

```js
function enviar() {
  let valor = 0
  let los_select = document.querySelectorAll('select')
  for (i = 0; i < los_select.length; i++) {
    valor += parseInt(document.getElementById(los_select[i].id).value);
  }
  console.log("valor enviado", valor);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="Pregunta1">Beber agua</label>
  <select id="Pregunta1" name="Pregunta1">
    <option value="0">Nunca</option>
    <option value="1">Casi nunca</option>
    <option value="2">A veces</option>
    <option value="3">Bastantes veces</option>
    <option value="4">Casi siempre</option>
  </select>

  <label for="Pregunta2">Ir al baño</label>
  <select id="Pregunta2" name="Pregunta2">
    <option value="0">Nunca</option>
    <option value="1">Casi nunca</option>
    <option value="2">A veces</option>
    <option value="3">Bastantes veces</option>
    <option value="4">Casi siempre</option>
  </select>
  <input type="button" value="Enviar" onclick="enviar()">
</form>
```

### Cambios realizados

1. En el HTML se han quitado los `onchange` porque no tenian demasiado sentido y eran propensos a causar errores.
2. En el javascript se ha eliminado también la función `obtenervalor()` pues ya no se usará en esta solución
3. Se ha quitado la linea `var valor = 0` porque no hace falta que esa variable ahora sea global. La podemos usar dentro de la función enviar() sin necesidad que salga de su ámbito.
4. Se ha modificado la función `enviar()` por esto:

```javascript
      let valor = 0
      let los_select = document.querySelectorAll('select')
      for (i = 0; i < los_select.length; i++) {
        valor += parseInt(document.getElementById(los_select[i].id).value);
      }
      console.log("valor enviado", valor);
```

donde en:

- ```javascript
      let valor = 0
  ```

definimos una variable local dentro solo de la función enviar(), que será la que usaremos para ir sumando los valores de los select.

- ```javascript
      let los_select = document.querySelectorAll('select')
  ```

mediante la función [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) creamos una lista de nodos de los elementos `select` que podremos recorrer con un bucle `for` despues y la almacenamos en la variable local `los_select`.

- ```javascript
      for (i = 0; i < los_select.length; i++) {
  ```

recorremos los elementos `select`uno a uno de la lista de nodos

- ```javascript
          valor += parseInt(document.getElementById(los_select[i].id).value);
  ```

Sumamos a `valor` el valor (**value**) en forma de número entero (**parseInt**) del elemento iterado en este ciclo (**los_select[i]**) con la función [getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) pasándole el valor de su id (**los_select[i].id**).

Esto nos recorrerá todos los select y los irá sumando hasta que al final, cuando salga del bucle, se muestre en consola el resultado con:

```javascript
      console.log("valor enviado", valor);
```

Cabe decir que cada vez que se ejecuta esta función se resetea el valor de `valor` y se vuelven a recorrer todos los `select` tal como acabo de explicar.

Comment: Si, esto era justo lo que quería. Muchas gracias por todo, te lo agradezco!

Comment: Bien, me alegro que te haya funcionado :-)  Saludos